The 'http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML:math' element is not declared in .NET Core
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><mi>a</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>b</mi><mo>&#xA0;</mo></math> 

This is the MathML that I am trying to validate against the MathML3 xsd, but this is failing in .NET Core with this exception:

The 'http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML:math' element is not declared.

This was working absolutely fine in .NET Framework flow.
I've tried some solutions from ChatGPT, but they are of no use.
Looking how to fix this in .NET Core.

a+b 

Hi @Charu Aggarwal, how do you get the error?  Not sure how is your project design, if any conflict with other js library, I suggest you create a new asp.net core project and try my code to check if it work or not.

Besides, try to use other browser to test if it can work well.

To troubleshoot the issue, please check:

if all required mathjax js files are loaded successfully from browser Network tab

if any error/exception occurs from browser Console tab or visual studio Output panel

if any conflict with other js library (can create a new asp.net core project to test)

try to use other browser to test if it can work well


A working demo you could follow
<h1>demo</h1>
<math xmlns="w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><mi>a</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>b</mi><mo>&#xA0;</mo></math>
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" async
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
    </script>        
}

Result:

